# Record payment for event registration in CiviCRM 4.7.16

Tags: civievent

We've recently upgraded to CiviCRM 4.7.16. I need to record a payment for an event registration. I used to go to the event record, click edit, and then there would be an option to record a payment. Now, that option does not seem to exist. When I add a new event participant, there is also no opportunity to record a payment. Anyone know how I can record a payment?
[image]

Comment: always worth self-verifying what is happening on one of the demo sites eg http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/

Answer (score 1):

I think i replicated this on Demo, but only if the Event was not set to be a Paid Event at civicrm/event/manage/fee?reset=1&action=update&id=x

As soon as i made it a Paid Event, the Record Payment option appeared when editing an Event Registration

Comment: Strange...I double-checked and all the events are set up as Paid Events, but none of them have the record payment option.

Comment: so is there an Edit i can make to the above answer to make it useful and then you can keep SE happy by accepting it

Comment: I'm not sure. I still can't record a payment for a Paid Event.

Comment: ok - maybe that is where it is useful to 'ground truth' by comparing/testing on demo site

Answer (score 0):

Has there been any resolution on this?

I am seeing this same behavior: a paid event, when registering through the backend, I do not get the option to record payment (I'm using a price set).

Running 4.7.15 in WP.

Note 1: I also do not get the selected profile with custom fields.
Note 2: This is for a past event (don't know if that matters)